# Почему не меняется цвет рамки?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var regV = /[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}/;    
var myEmail = $('#email');

myEmail.focus(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == $(this).prop('defaultValue'))
    {$(this).val('');
    }
});

myEmail.blur(function() {
    var userEmail = $(this).val();

    if (userEmail == '') {
    $(this).val($(this).prop('defaultValue'));
    }

    else if (userEmail.search(regV) == -1) {
    $(this).css('border','1px solid #cc0000');
    } 
    else {
    $(this).css('border','1px solid #00cc00');
      }
});

});
```

Comment: В джс нужно использовать по минимум ксс, или вообще заменять его навешиванием классом.
Если можно навесить класс - нужно его вешать, а в нем уже прописывать свойства.

Comment: Нужно давать ссылку на рабочий код, где то в песочнице, что бы могли люди давать ответ мгновенно, а не портить время на то что бы перенести его локально, и воспроизвести.

Comment: поменял css на addClass - от проблемы не избавился( видимо проблема не в них

Comment: какие-то выдуманные проблемы, всё работает: [http://jsfiddle.net/d4BQx/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/d4BQx/1/)

Comment: работает что? он должен менять цвет рамки, он не меняет. ты изменил в коде prop на attr. указание defaultValue с attr у меня не работают

Comment: >он должен менять цвет рамки, он не меняет

[пруф.](http://4put.ru/pictures/max/371/1140104.jpg)

Comment: прости не заметил с первого раза. проблема все равно осталась. у меня не работает указание defaultValue через attr. я без понятия почему, поэтому тут используется prop

Comment: это конечно все очень странно но вдруг все заработало. видимо с компом проблемы. прошу прощения за беспокойство

Comment: Ну верно код написан так что валидацию по меил нужно проходить когда ввели что то не дефолтное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очищайте или отключайте кеш браузера когда девелопите. Например Хром в этом плане может козлить до полной перезагрузки браузера.